# how to include transations in genesis block

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, private-blockchain, genesis

can one please advise how to include transactions in the `genesis` block of private ethereum network ?

can it be done via `genesis.json` similarly to contract using `code:` parameter ?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: testing purposes and expending my knowledge

Comment: so you can drill down into the source code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base on the current source code of ethereum, you cannot include tnx in the genesis block

```
type Genesis struct {
    Config     *params.ChainConfig `json:"config"`
    Nonce      uint64              `json:"nonce"`
    Timestamp  uint64              `json:"timestamp"`
    ExtraData  []byte              `json:"extraData"`
    GasLimit   uint64              `json:"gasLimit"   gencodec:"required"`
    Difficulty *big.Int            `json:"difficulty" gencodec:"required"`
    Mixhash    common.Hash         `json:"mixHash"`
    Coinbase   common.Address      `json:"coinbase"`
    Alloc      GenesisAlloc        `json:"alloc"      gencodec:"required"`

    // These fields are used for consensus tests. Please don't use them
    // in actual genesis blocks.
    Number     uint64      `json:"number"`
    GasUsed    uint64      `json:"gasUsed"`
    ParentHash common.Hash `json:"parentHash"`
}
```

Hope this help!